# WIN32: Obtain Graphics Card Information?

Tags: c, winapi, graphics

I'm trying to use the following DeviceContext struct to get some Graphics Driver information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In the documentation, the one parameter says it can be any "reasonable combination" of the given options.

What type are they?  Are they defined as pre-compiler fields?  And how do I find out each combined value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the flags are defined in the page you referenced.  The combined value is created by ORing the fields together, for example:

```
(DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE | DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE)
```

Comment: If I type them as fields, I get compiler errors.  Did I miss something about where they are defined?

Comment: Did you include `Wingdi.h` ?  It's mentioned towards the bottom of the page (under **Requirements**, next to **Header**).

Comment: It says (include Windows.h) which implies that should cover it.  I went ahead and tried it though.  Compiler still says DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE is undeclared.

Comment: Perhaps they want you to include both wingdi.h and windows.h.  Open up wingdi.h and see if any of the definitions are there.  If not, which version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: I have MinGW... perhaps that's why?

Comment: I have these:
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP 0x00000001
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_MULTI_DRIVER        0x00000002
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE      0x00000004
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER    0x00000008
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_VGA_COMPATIBLE      0x00000010
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_REMOVABLE           0x00000020
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_MODESPRUNED         0x08000000

  --  No DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE in there

Comment: Maybe DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP is a replacement and the docs are out of date (or vice versa)?  How do I separate these values?

Comment: Yes it would seem that DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP is a replacement.  You don't need to "separate these values".  They _basically_ mean the same thing.  Just use the one that your .h file defines.

Comment: I meant how to test to see if one existed in the mask value (StateFlags), which I just realized is a simple AND operation.  It seems to work fine now.  Thanks for your help!  (accepted and +1)